# 'ElasticTranscoder' does not exist in the namespace 'Amazon' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, namespaces

I am stuck in a problem in which I am using Amazon SDK for .NET 4.5 on VS 2012
What my problem is that my code does not resolve ElasticTranscoder namespace
-I installed SDK 3 times all old to latest versions
-Checked on VS 2010 and 0n VS 2012
-Tried adding ref like 100 times again n again
Cleaing and rebuilding solutions
It never changes.
I am stuck for two days now.
Help me in finding the correct way to resolve this class AmazonElasticTranscoderClient
Anyone?

```
  public void CreateJob(string Path, string bucket)
    {

    string accsessKey = CloudSettings.AccessKeyID;
    string secretKey = CloudSettings.SecreteKey;
    var etsClient = new **AmazonElasticTranscoderClient**(accsessKey,secretKey, RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hate to ask the obvious, but do you have these using statements at the top of your file:

```
using Amazon.ElasticTranscoder;
using Amazon.ElasticTranscoder.Model;
```

Also, try to create a brandnew project and pick the template:

```
Templates->Visual C#->AWS->App Services->Amazon Elastic Transcoder Sample
```

See if that installs and runs correctly - it does for me on VS2012 with .net 4.5

Comment: This answer helped me to reach there where I actually thought that where VS 2012 finding this ref from, turns out, it wasn't from the usual ref list, but it was getting it directly from a file as Dependency. So when I updated that file error ran away. Im happy thanks yo

Comment: In case someone here is dealing with an old project and running into the same error, check that Transcoder is added as a reference to all the projects that require it. I saw it was installed in NuGet and for the longest while did not realize that 2 projects had it, while 1 did not have it installed, causing the issues.